# How to Disable zuul filter for specific condition case and not sending to mapped URL

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have zuul filter implementation  with route config

```
 related:
      path: /api/search/related/**
      url: http://abc.xyz.neverhit.this.URl
```

and run implementation

```
 @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext context = getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = context.getRequest();
        UriComponents uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(recommendationsServiceHostname)
            .path("/recommendations/related")
            .query(request.getQueryString()).build();

        if (shouldRouteToRecommendationsService(request, uri)) {
            logger.info("Calling  proxy service");


            try {
                context.setRouteHost(new URL(uri.toString()));
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                logger.error("MalformedURLException for URL:" + uri.toString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Something here or Solution that should handle a request like a filter is not present.
        }
        return null;
}
```

Its working fine for if part and sending the request to proxy service. Problem is for else part. 
What I am looking for is in else scenario it should behave like filter never existed and it should handle request it was handling early executing API call from local code.

Any hack or proper solution  for this one ?

Comment: You should move code to `shouldFilter()`, return `true` in case you want to call proxy, return `false` if you don't want to.

Comment: Tried that..but in that case also when shouldFilter is returning false it is hitting URL configured and not internal API

Comment: shouldFilter decides only if run method of filter should be executed or not, returning false means that configured url would be executed, the part i m not getting is which internal API are you mentioning in the else bock

Comment: By internal API I mean to say calling existing code ignoring filter route configured. So If I reframe question I want to run a filter on the specific condition and ignore it all together if that condition is false.

Comment: in that case answer pointed by @HemantPatel is correct, when filter is never run zuul will hit http://abc.xyz.neverhit.this.URl if it find matching path i.e /api/search/related/**